# The (re)definition of $(this) in nested Jquery code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a simple question regarding $(this) and how it is defined and redefined in a chunk of code.

```
$('input').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if( question.find('.false').is(':visible') ){
      question.find('.false').hide("blind",{},350);  
    }
})
```

`$(this)` is unambiguously the input on the second line. Now, when we start the `if` statement, I have a new point of interest: `question.find('.false')`. If `$(this)` does not change to the new definition, is there an easier way to refer to `question.find('.false')`?

#### A follow-up for clarity

If I want to refer to `question.find('.false')` a few times in a longer version of the loop above, what's the best way to refer to it?

1. Define a new variable before the loop:

   ```
   var qfalse = question.find('.false')
   if( qfalse...){...qfalse this, qfalse that...
   ```
2. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will keep it's value until some new context redefines `this` (like in a `.each()` callback).  It keeps it's value everywhere in your function.

You can do what you were trying to do a bit simpler.  Rather than using the `if` test, just require the selector to be visible and only operate on the visible ones.

```
$('input').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    question.find('.false:visible').hide("blind",{},350);
})
```

In practice, you can call hide on all of them and the ones that are already hidden will be just ignored by the `.hide()` method.

```
$('input').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    question.find('.false').hide("blind",{},350);
})
```

If you want to use the same jQuery selector object in multiple places in your function and you can't just chain multiple methods together, then you would just use a local variable to assign the selector to and then use that variable:

```
$('input').live('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $falseQuestions = question.find('.false');
    // do whatever other operations you want on/with $falseQuestions here
    $falseQuestions.hide("blind",{},350);
})
```

Comment: Derp... I didn't even think of letting the selector do the work. +1

Comment: I've got a follow-up to your answer - what's the best (concise/most efficient) way to keep referring to the subject of a regular loop inside that loop? See my follow-up edit.

Comment: I added to my answer on your follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like the following?

```
$('input').live('click', function()
{
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $target = question.find('.false');

    if($target.is(':visible'))
    {
        $target.hide('blind', 350);  
    }
});
```

or, if you want to get *really* fancy, [write a wee little jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices):

```
(function ($)
{
    $.fn.hideIfVisible = function hideIfVisible()
    {
        if (this.is(':visible')) this.hide('blind', 350);
        return this;  
    };
}($));

$('input').live('click', function()
{
    $(this).addClass('active');
    question.find('.false').hideIfVisible();
});
```

---

**N.B.** [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Instead use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).